# Finite Polynomial Maps Between Affine Varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-geometry

I'm trying to figure out if various polynomial maps are finite, on map I'm considering is $\mathbb{A}^1 \rightarrow V(y^2 - x^3) $ that maps $t$ to $(t^2, t^3)$.

So I'm thinking that because this is a bijection, then it is finite. But to be honest I'm not sure if this is the case as I'm not entirely sure what makes a polynomial a finite map.

Comment: What do you mean by "finite" in this context?

Comment: I'm trying to work out if polynomial maps of various affine varieties are finite.

Comment: What are the function fields of the two varieties? If you know this, you can easily determine the degree and conclude the map is finite.

Comment: Is this $k[t^2, t^3]$ and $k[t]$, so since we know $k[t]$ is a finitely generated $k[t^2, t^3]$ - module, it is integral and therefore the map is finite?

Comment: @user901823 Yes! In particular, both have function field $k(t)$, so the map has degree $1$.